# Use timeouts in a HTTP Server?

Tags: http, timeout

Should I use Timeouts in a HTTP Server implementation?

E.g. if I get a request and create a HTTP Connection to listen to requests with a separate Thread, should this thread use timeouts?

Currently I don't use Timeouts in Debug Code, only in Production code, as to find the lockups in the Server.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you adheres the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), I don't forsee problems.